# Doctor Who episode where the name of the Doctor is revealed to be Victorius

Tags: doctor-who, episode-identification

I remember there is one episode where David Tennant plays the Doctor along with the Master and our Doctor Who's name is revealed as Victorius. Can anyone recall what episode that was?

Comment: I'd just like to point out that the episode doesn't reveal The Doctor's name as "Victorious". "The Time Lord Victorious" is a poetic way of saying "The Victorious Time Lord", or "The Time Lord Who Won/Always Wins".

Comment: You can accept an answer by clicking on the checkmark next to the answer or comment on said answer. Don’t edit your question to add a thank you.

Answer (score 4):

It was in the episode **The Waters of Mars**.

See the youtube video from official Doctor Who account:

You can read about it more in the [article on tardis.fandom.com](https://tardis.fandom.com/wiki/The_Waters_of_Mars_(TV_story)).